# ORA-04063: view "SYS.ALL_QUEUE_TABLES" has errors

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I tried to to see what tables are implemented in Oracle SQL Developer when I clicked "+" on the left hand side the window with this error has been shown, before I run this code:

```
BEGIN
   FOR cur_rec IN (SELECT object_name, object_type
                 FROM user_objects
                WHERE object_type IN
                         ('TABLE',
                          'VIEW',
                          'PACKAGE',
                          'PROCEDURE',
                          'FUNCTION',
                          'SEQUENCE'
                         ))
 LOOP
  BEGIN
     IF cur_rec.object_type = 'TABLE'
     THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE    'DROP '
                          || cur_rec.object_type
                          || ' "'
                          || cur_rec.object_name
                          || '" CASCADE CONSTRAINTS';
     ELSE
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE    'DROP '
                          || cur_rec.object_type
                          || ' "'
                          || cur_rec.object_name
                          || '"';
     END IF;
  EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS
     THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (   'FAILED: DROP '
                              || cur_rec.object_type
                              || ' "'
                              || cur_rec.object_name
                              || '"'
                             );
     END;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

SQL Developer stopped working, and I closed it, and when I run it again this error has been shown.

Thanks for any solutions.

Comment: Did you try searching at all first?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692693/how-to-solve-ora-04063-view-sys-all-queue-tables-has-errors

Comment: this is not solution for me

Comment: Run this query to see the error: `select * from dba_errors where name = 'ALL_QUEUE_TABLES';`.